# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): params.setLoggedIn is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm getting an error while passing the SetState from parent to child.

**Parent Component Index.js**

```
const Index = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
 
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar user={loggedIn} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={QuestionList} />
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} />
        <Route path="/addquestions" component={QuestionForm} />
        <Route path="/viewquestions" exact component={QuestionList} />
        <Route path="/viewquestions/:id" component={QuestionList} />
        <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

**ChildComponent**

```
const Login = (params) => {
  const initialCredentials = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
  };
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState(initialCredentials);
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setCredentials({ ...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleFinalSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();   
    validateUser(credentials);
  };

  const validateUser = async (data) => {
    const result = await loginUser(data);
    if (result.data.success) {
      setToken(result.data.token);
      setIsValid(true);    
      params.setLoggedIn(true);
    }

    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />;
  };

  if (isValid) return <Redirect to="/" />;

  return (
    <div className="container border border-gray mt-5 rounded">
      <h4 className="mt-3 text-info">Login</h4>
      <form action="/" className="mt-3" onSubmit={handleFinalSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control border border-info"
            id="formGroupExampleInput2"
            placeholder="Email"
            name="email"
            value={credentials.email}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
          <br></br>
          <input
            type="password"
            className="form-control border border-info"
            id="formGroupExampleInput2"
            placeholder="**********"
            name="password"
            value={credentials.password}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
          <br></br>

          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have a login form in the child component. When I submit the form I will validate the user. Once the user is valid.  then I will update the state of the parent component.
while updating the parent setLoggedIn state.
I'm getting the below error

**Error**

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: That error shows code that isn't in the question. Please may you make sure the example is a runnable [mcve]?

Comment: why not `Context`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why ?**

You are passing the props to route component not a login component Directly

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} />
```

**Solution**

You could pass the `setLoggedIn` props inside the child component props  instead of route component

```
<Route path="/login" component={(routeProps)=><Login {...routeProps} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn}/>}  />
```

Comment: I did not know the routeProps. Thanks, @Prasanth. Now it worked for me.

Comment: @Bumblebee routeProps does passing the default props of router to component like `match` ,`navigation` etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `props` to the component not the `Route Component`:

```
<Route path="/login" component={<Login setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} />} />;
```

and one more tip is to use `props` instead of `params` in your `login` component because it may confuse with the `params` from `react-router-dom` `location` object